# Java: Can I alter HTTP Headers And Read The Headers Server Side?

Tags: java, http-headers

I have a legacy Java webapp that does **MANY** redirects and forwards.   I'm trying to find a way in a ServletFilter to differentiate GET requests from those server side redirects and GET requests that come from the client side.

I was hoping to do that by adding an attribute as a flag, to the header before the redirect/forward is sent and then read it in the ServletFilter to route it accordingly.

I tried request.setAttribute("myflag", "yes") before the redirect and request.getAttribute("myflag") in the ServletFilter.  All I got were null values.

Can I modify headers server side and read those modifications server side?

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: You need to modify the response to pass the parameter to the next request, not modify the original request....

Comment: Didn't work, but thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `HttpServletRequestWrapper`, there is a comprehensive tutorial on how to do that here:

http://vangjee.wordpress.com/2009/02/25/how-to-modify-request-headers-in-a-j2ee-web-application/

Answer (score 0):

don't use request.setAttribute()/request.getAttribute() , it's  scopes on  forwards.

you can use Cookies.

Answer (score 0):

If your application sets a request attribute and then forwards the request, the filter (if executed) on the forwarded URI will see the request attribute values.

In contrast, if the application sets a request attribute and then issues a redirect on the response, the browser issues a new HTTP request to the next URI - so previous request object attributes are not persisted and you'll get null values.

You could use this technique to determine which requests were redirects vs forwards.

For example:

Servlet A executed at URI */webapp/a* calls `request.setAttribute("forward", Boolean.TRUE)` and then `response.sendRedirect("/webapp/b")`

If you have a servlet filter mapped to */webapp/b*, in the scenario above, `request.getAttribute("forward")` will be `null`.

If, however, */webapp/a* asks RequestDispatcher to [forward](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29) to /webapp/b, then the call to `request.getAttribute("forward")` within the servlet filter's `doFilter()` will yield `Boolean.TRUE` because the request object is the same.  It can then deduce that the request was forwarded (or [included](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29)) and not a redirect OR a direct GET request to */webapp/b*.